# How can create a flat file that has positions on SSIS

Tags: ssis

[image]

I need to produce a flat file like the above image using SSIS. I have the ordinal positions but I have not created a flat file like that

Comment: It looks like you're dealing with a mixed record/hierarchical file format and SSIS absolutely is a terrible choice for this. You end up either using a Script Component as destination to create the file, have a single column flat file destination and concatenate all the data to make the output row or just have a big Script Task and do all the work in .NET. Very painful regardless of which route you take

Comment: Thank you. let try it and I will give feedback